# from tkinter import * doesnt work anymore

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

I have been working on a project and everything was alright until I got this error:

```
File "D:\python\TKinter\amihaiRatson.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "C:\Users\amiha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2472, in <module>
    class Grid:
  File "C:\Users\amiha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2493, in Grid
    self.tk.call(
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

tkinter module suddenly not working..

Comment: That looks like you corrupted your standard library files, probably by directly editing them. Your best bet is probably to uninstall and reinstall Python.

Comment: Off-topic: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided.", so don't do that. Actually it might not be off-topic if there's a conflict with something else you've imported.

Comment: Tracebacks arent always accurate tho. Make sure there isnt something errant in your actual code. I've once had a major error that seem to indicate the python standard library but in my case it was cause by me having dual import statements in diff modules that became circular.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution.
I installed again the file *init*.py

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
import tkinter
```

or you can also use `import tkinter as tk` if you code is like `test = tk.Label()` and not `test = tkinter.Label()`